# Convert bmp to png and black colors to alpha

Tags: conversion, png, image-conversion, alpha-channel, bmp

I exported some sprites from the game Half-Life; however, they seem to have tones of black instead of the alpha channel. For example:

[image: Example]

How do I convert the black colors into alpha/transparency?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Windows, I recommend the freeware [Irfanview](https://www.irfanview.com/).

When you Save as PNG, select the options Save Transparent Color and Save Transparency as Alpha channel. As you are saving a dropper will allow you to click on an area with the color you want to define as Alpha (in this case Black)